# Selecting compared pairs from table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I don't really know how to describe it. I have a table:

```
ID |   Name  | Date
-------------------------
 1 | Mike    | 01.01.2016
 1 | Michael | 02.03.2016
 2 | Samuel  | 23.12.2015
 2 | Sam     | 05.03.2015
 3 | Tony    | 02.04.2012
```

I want to select pairs of IDs and Names with latest dates in each pair. The result here should be:

```
ID |   Name  | Date
-------------------------
 1 | Michael | 02.03.2016
 2 | Samuel  | 23.12.2015
 3 | Tony    | 02.04.2012
```

How do I achieve this?

Oracle Database 11g

Comment: how can we match the names basing on like condition it will create lot of data confusion .. is there any ID's for look alike names

Comment: Two(or more) rows have same "ID", I need to select the one that has greatest value of "Date" column.

Comment: What is your desired behaviour if there are two rows with the same `id` and maximum `date` values? Do you just return one of those rows or do you want both returned?

Comment: MT0, I just want one and It should not happen according to the logic of process writing these date columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the [`ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm):

```
SELECT id, name, "date"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "date" DESC ) rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

This requires only a single table scan (it does not have a self-join or correlated sub-query - i.e. `IN (...)` or `EXISTS(...)`).

Comment: looks interesting but unfortunately I couldn't adapt it to my original query :(

Comment: @ifuwannaride You should just be able to replace `table_name` with `( YOUR_QUERY )`. If you have issues then you can always post a new question with your actual query and ask how to apply `ROW_NUMBER()` to it to filter for the maximums.

Comment: wait, I think I did it, but I can not use "RN" in where clause, it says ORA00904 "RN" is invalid identifier

Comment: @ifuwannaride You need to make sure you have the alias for the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "date" DESC ) AS rn` - note the `rn` or `AS rn` at the end.

Comment: Ok I made it work, thank you! I'm sorry but I have one more question (and probably I need to open separate one) — What if I want to use pair of columns in PARTITION BY expression? like PARTITION BY (ID, ID2) , is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-select that returns each id and it's max date:

```
select * from table
where (id, date) in (select id, max(date) from table group by id)
```

Comment: This will require two table scans - it would be more efficient to use an analytic function. It will also return multiple rows for an `id` if there are rows with identical `id` and `date` values.

Comment: @MTO, yeah, those Oracle analytical functions seem to be handy, gotta learn to use them some day. Multiple rows in case of a tie is by purpose - of course!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
                 WHERE t.id = s.id and s.date > t.date)
```

Comment: This will require two table scans - it would be more efficient to use an analytic function. It will also return multiple rows for an `id` if there are rows with identical `id` and maximum `date` values.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the most efficient method is:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.date = (select max(date) from table t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

along with an index on `table(id, date)`.

This version should scan the table and look up the correct value in the index.

Or, if there are only three columns, you can use `keep`:

```
select id, max(date) as date,
       max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc) as name
from table
group by id;
```

I have found that this version works very well in Oracle.